# Get a collection with all possible HTML tags in Java

Tags: java, html

In Java, do you know how to obtain a Collection containing all the possible HTML tags, such as p, br, form, input, etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag

Comment: `java.util.EnumSet.allOf(javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag.class)`

Comment: There also seems [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.html#getAllTags())... If it has to be a Collection, then you can pass the array to the `Arrays#asList()` method.

Comment: @JonK you should post that as an answer, I would vote for it.

Comment: @Jae Heon Lee Thanks, it's exactly what i was looking for !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have suggested `javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag` as a source.

This is actually incorrect ... or at least, incorrect for most purposes.

The `Tag` enumeration is the set of elements that are understood by the Swing HTML classes.  There are in fact other HTML tags / elements that Swing's HTML classes don't understand!!  For example, the `<del>` and `<noscript>` elements were introduced in HTML 4.0, and yet the `Tag` enumeration doesn't include them.

To the best of my knowledge, the Java standard libraries do not provide a comprehensive collection of HTML elements.  And that's probably a good thing, because if they did, it would mean that each time the W3C released a new version of HTML, it would render earlier releases of Java "buggy".

---

So what is the solution?

Well if the Swing *subset* of the valid HTML elements is acceptable for your use-case, then use the `Tag` class.  Otherwise, your best bet would be to put all of the elements names into a configuration file, and read it into a collection on application  startup.

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element - lists (AFAIK) all known HTML elements, including obsolete, non-standard and deprecated ones.